# Why is every smooth quartic in $\Bbb{P}^3$ a K3 surface?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, k3-surfaces

Usually the first example of a K3 surface presented to us is the Fermat quartic $x_0^4+x_1^4+x_2^4+x_3^4=0$ in $\Bbb{P}_\Bbb{C}^3$.

But I've just found out that actually *any* smooth quartic in $\Bbb{P}^3$ is K3, and I'm trying to understand why.

I know that since $S\subset\Bbb{P}^3$ is a smooth quartic, then  in terms of linear equivalence we have $S\sim 4H$, where $H\subset \Bbb{P}^3$ is a hyperplane. By the adjunction formula:
$$K_S=(K_{\Bbb{P}
^3}+S)\big|_S\sim(-4H+4H)\big|_S=0$$

Now, to prove that $h^1(S,\mathcal{O}_S)=0$, I have no idea what to do.

I imagine that the Fermat quartic has nothing special, and we should be able to prove $h^1=0$ for any smooth quartic without additional difficulties. But I really don't know how to do that.

Comment: Do you know how to compute the cohomology of projective space? Did you consider the cohomology of the short exact sequence $0 \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X(-4) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_S \rightarrow 0$ where $X$ is $\mathbb{P}^3$?

Comment: To be a K3 surface, the quartic has to be smooth.

Comment: @Sasha, thanks for that! I've just corrected it

Comment: @user760870, no. Do you recommend some introductory reference for cohomology? I've looked it up in Shafarevich and Hartshorne, but they made me much more confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that we have the short exact sequence $$0 \rightarrow \mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(-4) \rightarrow \mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3} \rightarrow \mathscr{O}_S \rightarrow 0.$$ You get what you want then by considering the long exact sequence of cohomology groups plus the fact that $H^1(\mathbb{P}^3,\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}) = H^2(\mathbb{P}^3,\mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}^3}(-4)) = 0$.

**Edit**:

Since you were asking for some references, I would recommend [these](https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/alggeom-2002/alggeom-2002-c8.pdf) lecture notes or their [newer](https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/alggeom-2019/alggeom-2019-c16.pdf) (and different) version. In general I can only recommend the two lecture notes [full notes (older notes)](https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/alggeom-2002/alggeom-2002.pdf) and [very recent full notes](https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/alggeom-2019/alggeom-2019.pdf) by Gathmann. I think everything is well motivated, explained and contains detailed examples etc. He will also explain all the things you need to understand my answer, i.e. the long exact cohomology sequence associated to a short exact sequence and the computation of the cohomology of the twisted sheaves on projective spaces.

Comment: Best proof: very elementary,  works in characteristic $p$  and does not assume smoothness  !

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg I am honored to hear that from you as I am usually the one being very fond of your answers on SE. Yes, indeed. Here we do not need these assumptions to compute the irregularity (we still need smoothness for the adjunction formula, i.e for $K_S = 0$ though).

Comment: @TMO, I'm aware of what the $\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb{P}^3}$ e $\mathcal{O}_S$ mean, but I don't know how you buit the sequence and why $H^1(\Bbb{P}^3,\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb{P}^3})=H^2(\Bbb{P}^3,\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb{P}^3}(-4))=0$

Comment: @TMO actually, I don't even know a readable reference to learn these things. Hartshorne, Shafarevich and Beauville only confused me. If you have a recommendation, I'd be very happy

Comment: @rmdmc89 I edited the answer to include the most readable/understandable references I know where you can learn the things you need.

Answer (score 2):

Use Hodge theory $$H^1(S,\mathcal{O})=H^{0,1}(S)\subset H^1(S,\mathbb C),$$

together with Lefschetz hyperplane theorem $$H^1(S,\mathbb Z)\cong H^1(\mathbb P^3,\mathbb Z)=0.$$